# alternative to amazon cloud search

Tags: php, search, amazon-cloudsearch

We are looking for a search based solution for our website which will have millions of music records. 
We are looking for amazon cloud search but it will be a bit costly as we have to pay 90$ per month. 
Is there any cheaper /open source solution ?

Cheers

Comment: millions and cheaper don't go well toghter

Comment: yeah that is true. But ours will be a gradual progress . We are at 40K now . we are looking for a scalable solution.

Comment: write your own broski ? postgres + fts is trivial. Adding hstore to your tables and you can add your own inverted search metrics :D All for the cost of a single box. And it will handle millions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different cloud as well as opensource on premise products available, some of them are as below

- **www.elasticsearch.org** - It is opensource built on top of Apache Lucene. Scale well in cloud environment.
- **www.searchify.com** - SaaS offering just like Amazon Cloudsearch
- **sphinxsearch.com** - Opensource and easy to implement and maintain.
  Really good with predictable load.

I don't think you need to go for a cloud unless you have unpredictable high search load in different time slotf of a day or you don't have resources to manage or don't want to manage the self hosted solution.

Comment: We can add Apache solr to the list also.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of cloud based search providers in the heroku addons section:
Searchbox.io (Public Beta), 
Found ElasticSearch (Private Beta), 
IndexDen (Private Beta)

are some of those i could see that are not mentioned. Some of those also exists outside of Heroku on other cloud platforms.

I think that search is one of those plumbing stuff that you need to implement on any domain, and also a not very straightforward one, so its a good candidate for outsourcing..